# Maxlength constraint validation oddity in Chrome when using knockoutjs

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, validation, knockout.js

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ikramkgz/t581Lsgf/2)

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
</head>
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" maxlength="3" /></p>
<style>
input:invalid
{
  border-color: #e67b7b;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  var viewModel = 
    { firstName: ko.observable("Ikram")
    };

  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
</script>
```

In Chrome when there is old value that exceeds maxlength, constraint validation does not validate until we edit input. When we start to edit it gets red.

In IE it works as expected, it gets red(validates) at the start when we load the page with old value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look like a knockout issue.

```
<input value='my longname' maxlength="3" />
```

Also does not show an error in chome.

Here is a knockout workaround.

First create a hasError computed obseable.

```
 function hasErrorComputed(){   
     return viewModel.firstName().length > 3;
 }
 iewModel.hasError = ko.computed(hasErrorComputed);
```

Then bind css to hasError.

```
<input data-bind="css: {error: hasError}, value: firstName" maxlength="3" />
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afrievalt/t581Lsgf/45/)

A more eloquent solution can be achieved with custom-bindings: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Or extenders http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html

Please reach out for more details.